# Unable to click button in android

Tags: android, button, layout

I'm unable to click button. I've done this before but this time i dont know why its not working. Scrollview is working fine but buttons in it are not being clicked.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Black" >




    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
           <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"

            android:text="TNT"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez1"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White" 
             android:text="HIGH VOLTAGE"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez2"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="LET THERE BE ROCK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez3"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="POWERAGE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez4"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="IF U WANT BLOOD" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez5"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="BACK IN BLACK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez6"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White" 
             android:text="DIRTY DEEDS DONE CHEAP"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez7"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="FOR THOSE ABOUT TO ROCK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez8"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White" 
             android:text="FLICK OF THE SWITCH"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez9"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="JAILBREAK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez10"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="FLY ON THE WALL" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez11"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="WHO MADE WHO" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez12"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="BLOW UP YOUR VIDEO" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez13"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="THE RAZORS EDGE" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez14"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="HIGHWAY TO HELL" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez15"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="BALLBREAKER" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez16"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="BLACK ICE" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez17"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:text="THE RAZORS EDGE" />



       </RelativeLayout>
       </ScrollView>
       </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my java class

```
    package com.surajmal.rocklegends2;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
     import android.widget.Button;

      public class Acdc extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acdc);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez2);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez3);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez4);
    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez5);
    Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez6);
    Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez7);
    Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez8);
    Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez9);
    Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez10);
    Button button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez11);
    Button button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez12);
    Button button13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez13);
    Button button14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez14);
    Button button15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez15);
    Button button16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez16);
    Button button17 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez17);
    Button button18 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoneez18);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
    button7.setOnClickListener(this);
    button8.setOnClickListener(this);
    button9.setOnClickListener(this);
    button10.setOnClickListener(this);
    button11.setOnClickListener(this);
    button12.setOnClickListener(this);
    button13.setOnClickListener(this);
    button14.setOnClickListener(this);
    button15.setOnClickListener(this);
    button16.setOnClickListener(this);
    button17.setOnClickListener(this);
    button18.setOnClickListener(this);

 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttoneez1:
        String namaste = "1";
        Intent dex = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dex.putExtra("url", 1);
        startActivity(dex);
        finish();

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez2:

        String a = "2";
        Intent q = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        q.putExtra("url", 2);
        startActivity(q);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez3:
        String b = "3";
        Intent w = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        w.putExtra("url", 3);
        startActivity(w);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez4:
        String c = "4";
        Intent e = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        e.putExtra("url", 4);
        startActivity(e);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez5:
        String d = "5";
        Intent r = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        r.putExtra("url", 5);
        startActivity(r);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez6:
        String f = "6";
        Intent t = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        t.putExtra("url", 6);
        startActivity(t);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez7:
        String g = "7";
        Intent y = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        y.putExtra("url", 7);
        startActivity(y);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez8:
        String h = "8";
        Intent u = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        u.putExtra("url", 8);
        startActivity(u);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez9:
        String j = "9";
        Intent i = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        i.putExtra("url", 9);
        startActivity(i);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez10:
        String k = "10";
        Intent o = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        o.putExtra("url", 10);
        startActivity(o);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez11:
        String l = "11";
        Intent p = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        p.putExtra("url", 11);
        startActivity(p);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez12:
        String qq = "12";
        Intent aa = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        aa.putExtra("url", 12);
        startActivity(aa);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez13:
        String ww = "13";
        Intent ss = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        ss.putExtra("url", 13);
        startActivity(ss);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez14:
        String ee = "14";
        Intent dd = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dd.putExtra("url", 14);
        startActivity(dd);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez15:
        String ee1 = "15";
        Intent dd1 = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dd1.putExtra("url", 15);
        startActivity(dd1);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez16:
        String ee2 = "16";
        Intent dd2 = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dd2.putExtra("url", 16);
        startActivity(dd2);

        break;

    case R.id.buttoneez17:
        String ee3 = "17";
        Intent dd3 = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dd3.putExtra("url", 17);
        startActivity(dd3);

        break;

    case R.id.buttoneez18:
        String ee4 = "18";
        Intent dd4 = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dd4.putExtra("url", 18);
        startActivity(dd4);

        break;


    default:
        break;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

And this is where the intent  is received

```
    package com.surajmal.rocklegends2;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class Acdctwo extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent x=getIntent();
    int y=x.getIntExtra("url", 0);

    switch(y){
    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_tnt);
        break;
    case 2:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_highvoltage);
        break;

    case 3:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_letthereberock);
        break;
    case 4:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_powerage);
        break;
    case 5:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_blood);

        break;
    case 6:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_black);

        break;
    case 7:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_dirty);
        break;
    case 8:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_forthose);
        break;

    case 9:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_flick);
        break;
    case 10:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_jailbreak);
        break;
    case 11:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_fly);
        break;
    case 12:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_whomade);
        break;
    case 13:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_blow);
        break;
    case 14:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_razor);
        break;
    case 15:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_live);
        break;
    case 16:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_highway);
        break;
    case 17:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_ballbreaker);
        break;
    case 18:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_bonfire);
        break;
    case 19:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_stiff);

        break;
    case 20:
        setContentView(R.layout.acdc_black);
        break;
    default:
        setContentView(R.layout.metallica1);
        break;

    }
}

    }
```

Comment: to make your life easier why not start with 1 button, once that works then add the rest?

Comment: Try to print a message at the very beginning of your `onClick(View)` method and tell us if it prints out. If it does it means that the problem is somewhere ahead, in your switch.

Comment: I have checked with same code. This work fine. Please use some log and check again :)

Comment: Did you try to clean and refresh your project ? Sometimes this is as simple.

Comment: yes the code is working fine...

Comment: My onclickview itself isnt working

Comment: isnt working on my nexus 4

Comment: your code is working fine on the device still you can try my answer hope this will solve your problem

Comment: @ChiragBhardwaj i would i like to suggest you instead of using so much of buttons why u don't go with listview that will be a better approach

Comment: Still isnt working on my nexus 4. Ive made the apk because even i thought the code was alright but there's something why these buttons are not being clicked

Comment: @Gaurav I'm not good with list view. I used it in my previous app but this time i thought about going with buttons instead

Comment: i ready to help in that beacause using so much of button will not suggest if u wish i can help you @ChiragBhardwaj

Comment: This project is almost over with buttons man cant switch to anything now. Buttons are still not clicking.

Comment: Your code is perfect i have used that i don't know why on your device i have use that on 3 device karbon ,samsung and micromax on all three it's working fine

Comment: My fault guys the problem wasn't with this code. It was the problem with the code that called it. My code called the xml file instead of the  class that used it. Sorry guys and big thanks.@gaurav,@amit,@minde,@srikanth,@mdoran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do like this Might help you some how

**onCreate**

```
private ButtonClicked clicked = new ButtonClicked();
```

then set the **onclickListner** of all the buttons

```
buttonOn.setOnClickListener(clicked);
buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(clicked);
```

then **ButtonClicked**

```
class ButtonClicked implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonOn:
                on();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSearch:

                start();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDesc:
                makeDiscoverable();
                break;
            case R.id.off:
                off();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.surajmal.rocklegends2;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;

      public class Acdc extends Activity{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acdc);
 }


public void Button_Click(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttoneez1:
        String namaste = "1";
        Intent dex = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dex.putExtra("url", 1);
        startActivity(dex);
        finish();

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez2:

        String a = "2";
        Intent q = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        q.putExtra("url", 2);
        startActivity(q);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez3:
        String b = "3";
        Intent w = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        w.putExtra("url", 3);
        startActivity(w);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez4:
        String c = "4";
        Intent e = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        e.putExtra("url", 4);
        startActivity(e);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez5:
        String d = "5";
        Intent r = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        r.putExtra("url", 5);
        startActivity(r);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez6:
        String f = "6";
        Intent t = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        t.putExtra("url", 6);
        startActivity(t);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez7:
        String g = "7";
        Intent y = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        y.putExtra("url", 7);
        startActivity(y);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez8:
        String h = "8";
        Intent u = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        u.putExtra("url", 8);
        startActivity(u);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez9:
        String j = "9";
        Intent i = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        i.putExtra("url", 9);
        startActivity(i);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez10:
        String k = "10";
        Intent o = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        o.putExtra("url", 10);
        startActivity(o);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez11:
        String l = "11";
        Intent p = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        p.putExtra("url", 11);
        startActivity(p);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez12:
        String qq = "12";
        Intent aa = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        aa.putExtra("url", 12);
        startActivity(aa);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez13:
        String ww = "13";
        Intent ss = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        ss.putExtra("url", 13);
        startActivity(ss);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez14:
        String ee = "14";
        Intent dd = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dd.putExtra("url", 14);
        startActivity(dd);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez15:
        String ee1 = "15";
        Intent dd1 = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dd1.putExtra("url", 15);
        startActivity(dd1);

        break;
    case R.id.buttoneez16:
        String ee2 = "16";
        Intent dd2 = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dd2.putExtra("url", 16);
        startActivity(dd2);

        break;

    case R.id.buttoneez17:
        String ee3 = "17";
        Intent dd3 = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dd3.putExtra("url", 17);
        startActivity(dd3);

        break;

    case R.id.buttoneez18:
        String ee4 = "18";
        Intent dd4 = new Intent(Acdc.this, Acdctwo.class);
        dd4.putExtra("url", 18);
        startActivity(dd4);

        break;


    default:
        break;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

And layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Black" >




    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
           <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
            android:text="TNT"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez1"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White" 
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="HIGH VOLTAGE"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez2"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="LET THERE BE ROCK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez3"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="POWERAGE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez4"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="IF U WANT BLOOD" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez5"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="BACK IN BLACK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez6"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White" 
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="DIRTY DEEDS DONE CHEAP"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez7"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="FOR THOSE ABOUT TO ROCK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez8"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White" 
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="FLICK OF THE SWITCH"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez9"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="JAILBREAK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez10"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="FLY ON THE WALL" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez11"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="WHO MADE WHO" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez12"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="BLOW UP YOUR VIDEO" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez13"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="THE RAZORS EDGE" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez14"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="HIGHWAY TO HELL" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez15"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="BALLBREAKER" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez16"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="BLACK ICE" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoneez18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttoneez17"
            android:background="@drawable/yeah23"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:onClick="Button_Click"
             android:text="THE RAZORS EDGE" />



       </RelativeLayout>
       </ScrollView>
       </RelativeLayout>
```